# Is manually changing data mapping in EF common practice?

Tags: entity-framework

I am a beginner at EF. 
Is manually changing data mapping in EF common practice?

For example i want to create GenericRepository but primary keys has different names CuctomerID, OrderID e.t.c

So I need edit mappings for those POCO classes.

So what I should do if tables structure updated periodically?

If I automatically update edmx and POCO files will that destroy all changes applied to POCO?

Comment: If you are creating a `GenericRepository` it should be able to handle all these cases otherwise it wont be `Generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing names of properties in the designer for EDMX **is common practice** - that is mapping. When you update EDMX from database it should keep your changes unless you did some big change to the database.

Comment: thank you for help). so i am going just change ProductId,OrderId e.t.c in conceptual model to simple id property)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common practice and the EDMX file supports this behavior.

Your EDMX file consists of three parts.

- Store schema definition language (SSDL)
- Conceptual schema definition language (CSDL)
- Mapping specification language (MSL)

When you run an Update from Database command, the SSDL part will be updated 
and if for example, you have new tables you get an option to add them to your Conceptual model.

So if you make changes in your Conceptual Schema and then update the database only the SSDL and the MSL will be changed.